# Position divs on screen to be in a particular shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to position certain divs in the middle of the screen to make a pearl necklace type of shape. The shape should look something like this:

```
     0 0
   0     0
   0     0 
    0   0
      0
      0
```

I would like to do this with jquery on a mobile ionic app. My goal is to have these "beads" be centered on the screen. Here's the html I'm using for my view which I am happy to change if need be:

```
<ion-view view-title="Pray the Rosary" id="prayer">
  <ion-content>
    <div id="prayer-content">
    <div id="current">Sorrowful Mysteries</div>
    <div ng-click="play()" id="play">Begin</div>
    <div ng-click="pause()" id="pause">Pause</div>
      <div class="bead" ng-class="inactive" id="bead14"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead13"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead12"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead11"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead10"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead9"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead8"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead7"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead6"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead5"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead4"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead3"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead2"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead1"></div>
      <div id="cross"><img src="../img/images/cross.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My current CSS:

```
/*Prayer content*/
#prayer-content{
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
.bead{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #8ee5f5;
}
.active{
  background: #006baf;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
}
#cross{
  position: absolute;
  top: 320px;
  left: 154px;
}
#bead1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 292px;
  left: 196px;
}
#bead2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 266px;
  left: 196px;
}
#bead3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 240px;
  left: 196px;
}
#bead4{
  position: absolute;
  top: 201px;
  left: 191px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
#bead5{
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 223px;
}
#bead6{
  position: absolute;
  top: 155px;
  left: 236px;
}
#bead7{
  position: absolute;
  top: 126px;
  left: 248px;
}
#bead8{
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 240px;
}
#bead9{
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  left: 215px;
}
#bead10{
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  left: 180px;
}
#bead11{
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 155px;
}
#bead12{
  position: absolute;
  top: 126px;
  left: 151px;
}
#bead13{
  position: absolute;
  top: 153px;
  left: 160px;
}
#bead14{
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 173px;
}
```

It looks good on the iphone view but on the ipad it looks jumbled... Can I do this with javascript to make sure the beads stay aligned in the center at all times?

Thanks for your input!

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tetxwj8k/

Comment: It would be awesome if you could add a jsfiddle link that shows this.

Comment: I added the link. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I tried changing the resolution and testing using Chrome's device toolbar and it still appeared perfectly. If that'd be possible, can you please add screenshots for how it looks like on an iPad?

Does it look "jumbled"? If so, how? or is it just not at the center?

Comment: Yes, I figured this out. It was not centered so I created a div that was the width of the beads shape and centered the div with `margin: 0, auto; position: relative;` and that kept it right at the center, no matter the screen size. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
/*Prayer content*/
#prayer-content{
  width: 128px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 489px;
  margin-top: -35px;
}
.bead{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #8ee5f5;
}
.active{
  background: #006baf;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
}
#cross{
  position: absolute;
  top: 320px;
  left: 154px;
}
.bead{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #8ee5f5;
}
.active{
  background: #006baf;
  border: 1px dashed #fff;
}
#cross{
  position: absolute;
  top: 320px;
  left: 6px;
}
#bead1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 292px;
  left: 49px;
}
#bead2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 266px;
  left: 49px;
}
#bead3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 240px;
  left: 49px;
}
#bead4{
  position: absolute;
  top: 201px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
#bead5{
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 87px;
}
#bead6{
  position: absolute;
  top: 155px;
  left: 105px;
}
#bead7{
  position: absolute;
  top: 126px;
  left: 117px;
}
#bead8{
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 100px;
}
#bead9{
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  left: 70px;
}
#bead10{
  position: absolute;
  top: 76px;
  left: 30px;
}
#bead11{
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  left: 0px;
}
#bead12{
  position: absolute;
  top: 126px;
  left: -10px;
}
#bead13{
  position: absolute;
  top: 153px;
  left: 0px;
}
#bead14{
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Pray the Rosary" id="prayer">
  <ion-content>
    <div id="prayer-content">
    <div id="current">Sorrowful Mysteries</div>
    <div ng-click="play()" id="play">Begin</div>
    <div ng-click="pause()" id="pause">Pause</div>
      <div class="bead" ng-class="inactive" id="bead14"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead13"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead12"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead11"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead10"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead9"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead8"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead7"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead6"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead5"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead4"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead3"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead2"></div>
      <div class="bead" id="bead1"></div>
      <div id="cross"><img src="../img/images/cross.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here's my solution to keeping it centered: